# Using data to set properties of a GridView

Tags: c#, webforms

I need to set the 'ReadOnly' property of a BoundField in a GridView to the value of a bit field in the recordset that is being displayed by the same GridView.

I am aware I could achieve this in code, but I was wondering, out of interest, if it's possible to do this declaratively inside the property using a <% %> snippet?

Cheers,

Jamie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do this.  Create a TemplatedField and in the binding statement use either

```
<%# ((Employee)Container.DataItem).IsApproved ? "yes" : "no" %>
```

or you can use a method from the code-behind

```
<%# FormatBool(((Employee)Container.DataItem).IsApproved) %>
```

where FormatBool is a property in your code-behind

```
protected string FormatBool(bool value)
{
   if (value)
      return "yes";
   return "no";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to bind to properties, I would use a TemplateField and then set the behavior there.  This is only if you can't use the code, otherwise, that is your best bet.

I don't think there's a way to bind the detail of a BoundColumn directly.

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to find a way of manipulating the properties of either the BoundField or the TemplateField declaratively based on the DetailView's data.

Bendewey very charitably assumed I was binding to a business object when in fact I am dealing with the data directly in this instance - apologies for not making that clear.

My solution in the code behind was the following:

```
    protected void DetailsView1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DetailsView dv = (DetailsView)sender;

        if (dv.DataItemCount > 0)
        {
            DataRowView data = (DataRowView)dv.DataItem;
            bool isFixed = (bool)data["IsFixed"];

            if (isFixed)
            {
                dv.Rows[2].Enabled = false;
                dv.Rows[6].Enabled = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

I was disapointed that I had to reference the rows I wanted to disable by index. Possibly there's a way of referencing these rows by their data field without iterating through all the rows, but I couldn't find it at first glance.

Thanks for the help!